To which directory should NiFi_HOME point in new NiFi 2.0.0 version?
I loaded latest version of NiFi 2.0.0 from
https://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.lua?path=/nifi/2.0.0/nifi-2.0.0-source-release.zip
I set up Java_HOME which did not work from the start (JDK21).
Now I have a problem with the Bootstrap, when I try to start it using nifi.cmd start with administrator rights (I have all rights to the NiFi directory and all subdirectories) I get an error:
Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.nifi.bootstrap.BootstrapProcess
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.nifi.bootstrap.BootstrapProcess
As I see it sets up NiFi_HOME completely wrong as:
nifi\nifi-framework-bundle\nifi-framework\nifi-resources\src\main\resources
Apart of that that this directory does not contain bootstrap, it also has only directories "bin" and "conf".
NiFi.cmd configures it as "set BOOTSTRAP_LIB_DIR=%NIFI_HOME%\lib\bootstrap".
I suspect that for NiFi 2.0.0 it should be set for some other directory, but it is the first time I see this new version.
Can anyone point out what and where should I change?
To which directory should NIFI_HOME point and if it is connected with this Bootstrap problem?
I tried to configure NiFi_HOME manually but I have no idea to which directory it should point in the new version of NiFi.
